# Folium and timestamped GeoJSON issue , not reading the data correctly

Tags: python, visualisation, folium

I am having issues with Folium and using `TimestampedGeoJson`. I have the following dataframe structure below. I am trying to display this data with Folium and a time slider to be used on the date field:

```
    Date        Geometry
0   2016-03-09  POLYGON ((10.00000 25.00000, 10.00000 25.00000, 10.00000 
                          26.00000, 12.00000 26.00000, 18.00000 25.00000,
                          17.00000 25.00000))
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial below and still not working:
https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-nyc-bike-data-on-interactive-and-animated-maps-with-folium-plugins-c2d7645cd19b

```
def create_geojson_features(df):

    features = []   
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        features = []
        feature = {
            'type': 'Features',
            'geometry': {
                'type':'MultiPolygon',
                'coordinates':(row['Geometry'])
            },
            'properties': {
                'times':(pd.to_datetime(row['Date'])),
            }
        }
        features.append(feature)

    return features

df1 = create_geojson_features(df)
world_map = folium.Map(location=[10,0],tiles="cartodbposition",zoom_start=2,max_zoom=6,min_zoom=3)

    TimestampedGeoJson(
          df1
        , period='P1D'
        , add_last_point=True
        , auto_play=False
        , loop=False
        , max_speed=1
        , loop_button=True
        , date_options='YYYY-MM-DD'
        , time_slider_drag_update=True
    ).add_to(world_map)
```

The geometry and times are not being read correctly via the function and/or the `TimestampedGeoJson`. Also, in the coordinates field is a shapely object once the function `create_geojson_features` is executed.

Comment: In properties of geojson, you should use time instead of times. In addition to this correction, pd.to_datetime makes date string timestamp object, not a valid json serializable value. 
You can use string directly or convert via strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: I made those changes and still code does not work. When I try to load an image to my local server and open up the console. Nothing gets loaded, and im getting the "uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected token '<'

Comment: The major issue is how to read these coordinates correctly and I have not found a clear answer anywhere.

Comment: How to use polygon coordinates with the TimestampedGeoJson API?

Comment: I think it is about how you create geojson. Why not just use geodataframe in folium? folium allows you to use your geodataframe as input, or you can convert it like df.to_json()

Comment: df.to_json does work in folium but I have not been able to pass df to TimestampedGeoJson

Comment: ```TimestampedGeoJson``` wants a format that the ```create_geojson_features``` is trying to do

Comment: With point data , the script above works but with polygon data I have not been able to able to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to transform geodataframe to geojson is using this function:

[image]

```
# list
polygon=[]

for i in shapes_gpd.index:
    geom = str(shapes_gpd[shapes_gpd.index==i].unary_union)
    positi = geom.find("(")
    coord1 = geom[positi:]
    coord2 = coord1.replace(")), ((",")),((")
    coord3 = coord2.replace(", ","),(")
    coord4 = str([coord3.replace(" ", ", ")]).replace("'(","(").replace(")'", ")")
    coord5 = coord4.replace("[(((", "[((").replace(")))]", "))]")
    coord6 = ast.literal_eval(coord5.replace("[((", "[(((").replace("))]",")))]"))
    coordgrup = {
        'coordinates': coord6,
        'group': shapes_gpd['group'].iloc[i], 
        'time': shapes_gpd['time'].iloc[i],
        'color': shapes_gpd['color'].iloc[i], 
    }
    polygon.append(coordgrup)
```

[Source](https://github.com/erickmattoso/Syrian_War/blob/main/notebooks/01-war_syria.ipynb)